# Is there any way I could use self from a method as an Rc<RefCell<T>>?

Tags: rust

I have a struct (Foo) that has an `Rc<RefCell<Bar>>` field, Bar has a method that gets called by a `Rc<RefCell<Bar>>`, in that method it gets a reference to a Foo and I would like to set that `Rc<RefCell<Bar>>` in in that Foo to the Bar that called the method.

Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    thing: Rc<RefCell<Bar>>,
}

struct Bar;

impl Foo {
    pub fn set_thing(&mut self, thing: Rc<RefCell<Bar>>) {
       self.thing = thing;
    }
}

impl Bar {
    pub fn something(&mut self) {
        // Things happen, I get a &mut to a Foo, and here I would like to use this Bar reference
        // as the argument needed in Foo::set_thing            
    }
}

// Somewhere else
// Bar::something is called from something like this:
let my_bar : Rc<RefCell<Bar>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Bar{}));
my_bar.borrow_mut().something();
// ^--- I'd like my_bar.clone() to be "thing" in the foo I get at Bar::something
```

Is the only way to do what I want to add another parameter to `Bar::something` accepting an `Rc<RefCell<Bar>>`? It feels redudant, when I'm already calling it from one.

```
    pub fn something(&mut self, rcSelf: Rc<RefCell<Bar>>) {
        foo.set_thing(rcSelf);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two main choices here:

- Use a static method:

  ```
  impl Bar {
      pub fn something(self_: Rc<RefCell<Bar>>) {
          …
      }
  }

  Bar::something(my_bar)
  ```
- Conceal the fact that you’re using `Rc<RefCell<X>>`, wrapping it in a new type with the single field `Rc<RefCell<X>>`; then other types can use this new type rather than `Rc<RefCell<Bar>>` and you can make this `something` method work with `self`. This may or may not be a good idea, depending on how you use it. Without further details it’s hard to say.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll be going with a static method.

If I'm understanding the second choice correctly, making a newtype still feels a bit too redundant when looking at my code, since I'd have the `Bar` struct with all its data, and then some `BarRef` newtype, and I'd have to impl on one or the other depending on how some method works.

In any case would you mind expanding a bit on when it may (or not) be a good idea to do this?

Comment: The second way also works fairly well, more concise for users. But it feels like quite some extra code for a simple problem.